# Permission denied when uploading file to android device

Tags: android, file-upload, permissions, installation, device

I suddenly got this error message from all my projects when I try to run them on my device: This just came from nowhere, I have tried everything and Im stuck, also added this to my manifest `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`. There is enough of storage, If I go to the adb shell and to "ls" in /data/local/tmp/ I can see com.example.xreg.myalarm there. I also can delete it. But If I do a "ls" in /data/local is says "  shell@hwG630-U20:/data/local $ ls
ls
opendir failed, Permission denied" What the hell has happened???

Anyone with any ideas howto fix this or find a workaround???

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: huawei-g630_u20-086361d8bade
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\xreg\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAlarm\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.xreg.myalarm
Installing com.example.xreg.myalarm
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.xreg.myalarm"
BT INFO: 2.2
open: Permission denied
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.xreg.myalarm
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have room on the device, maybe.  Also, in the future, please consider formatting your post to make it easier to read.  Thanks!

Comment: Problem was in the device itself! Solved by a factory reset!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that message ([INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]) when I do not have enough space to install the app or when the internal storage is not accesible (in my case due to a storage damage).